# Variable Reference for COUNTIF Criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, matrix, excel-formula, countif

I want to count dates within a matrix using COUNTIF with each cell using different reference cells for the criteria.

I would like the reference in the COUNTIF criteria to vary positionally for each cell in the range (similar to how conditional formatting works). It seems that COUNTIF does not work this way. The reference in the criteria is stationary and each cell determination uses that one reference.

I could perhaps use COUNTIFS and have a criteria set for each column, but in my real workbook I'm dealing with too many to make that a simple solution.

The linked image shows an example of the kind of workbook I'm using and the formula in its current state. The red filled cells are expired trainings based on the renewal time.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

`=COUNTIF(B6:E6,"<"&TODAY()-(365*$B2))`

[image: Example Workbook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:E3<(TODAY()-($B$2:$E$2*365))))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much. I will do some research to SUMPRODUCT to totally grasp what it's doing here.

Comment: @knm in about 3 minutes you can mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.